# Calling function from web3, getting transaction hash but transaction status fail

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, web3js, rinkeby

I have a contract deployed on rinkeby with function name userexist();

Now, calling this function from web3 :

```
Web3.eth.defaultAccount = '0x262b76dF1dCb6542AA4a19296A824F0fDD1B4B04';

Web3.personal.unlockAccount(Web3.eth.defaultAccount,'******', 15000)

var getData = contractinstance.userexist();

var transaction = Web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: Web3.eth.defaultAccount,
    to: '0x3FCc01A2d64978962c144d67E52897AAaf69d1C7',
    data: getData,
    gas: 90000
});

console.log(transaction);
```

Getting result as  :
0x9ea36225341791b471afd309658a146a0881bee6c0a00d1d52f837c78df624ea

Now when I check this on rinkeby
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x9ea36225341791b471afd309658a146a0881bee6c0a00d1d52f837c78df624ea

It show transaction status as failed.....

I tried twice but getting same error

Can anyone help please .....

Thanks In Advanced

Comment: it is normal to get the transaction hash and have the trnsaction fail. so the problem is probably from the `contractinstance.userexist();` call. paste more code if you have any

Comment: Try ``var getData = contractinstance.userexist.getData()``